# Apache Proxy redirect

Tags: apache, ubuntu, redirect, proxy

I have set a forward proxy in apache and it works, when i set my mozilla to use the proxy i see that every request gets through it.

But i want to redirect every of those requests to a different page. So far my code is only redirecting when i go to localhost.
How can i make every request that goes in the proxy to redirect to another page ?

My conf file is the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:8888>
RewriteEngine  on
ProxyRequests On
ProxyPass * http://google.com/

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error_forward_proxy.log
 CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access_forward_proxy.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

you add like below :

```
Redirect "/" "http://www.example.com/"
```

it will redirect when you access

Comment: As i wrote this will work only if i type localhost:8888 in browser.
I want to write in browser google.com and then get redirected to www.example.com instead of google.com.